# Remove comma from a string surrounded by double quotes and the surrounding double quotes as well

Tags: regex, regex-group

Input String

```
Arab World,ARB,"Adolescent fertility rate (births per 1000 women ages 15-19)",SP.ADO.TFRT,1960,133.56090740552298
```

Output String

```
Arab World,ARB,Adolescent fertility rate (births per 1000 women ages 15-19),SP.ADO.TFRT,1960,133.56090740552298
```

Input String

```
Arab World,ARB,"International migrant stock, total",SM.POP.TOTL,1960,3324685.0
```

Output String

```
Arab World,ARB,International migrant stock total,SM.POP.TOTL,1960,3324685.0
```

Comment: In the first example you did not remove the comma in the result. But more importantly, what is the problem? What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: What langage are you using? Does it have a library for reading CSV files? You should use that instead of trying to do it with a regexp. This type of application is difficult for regexp in general.

Comment: Its typo. 1,000=1000

Comment: @barmar i want to do this using unix script.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a two part process here.

## Step 1 Split The String

This regex will split your string on commas. Any commas nested inside quotes will be ignored for this operation. Additionally the surrounding quotes will be removed in the same operation.

Regex:

```
(?:^|,)(?=[^"]|(")?)"?((?(1)[^"]*|[^,"]*))"?(?=,|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/rJ5oF9/1

to simply split your strings on the delimiting comma

## Step 2 Replace the commas

Iterate through the array of strings and replace the commas in each

The regex:  `,`

Replace with:  nothing

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/pA1iA6/1

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using two regexes (I'll present them here in a perl one-liner). First, use the following to delete the first comma found between quotes (note that subsequent commas within the same set of quotes are not removed):

```
s/"((?!").)*?\K,(((?!").)*")/$2/g
```

The next regex removes pairs of quotes:

```
s/"(((?!").)*)"/$1/g
```

Some code that could implement these regexes could be as follows:

```
perl -plane 's/"((?!").)*?\K,(((?!").)*")/$2/g; s/"(((?!").)*)"/$1/g' originalFile.csv > newFile.csv
```